# Text file(.txt) in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I am new to android development. Can I add .txt file in my app and use it to show text(the text file contains a paragraph of description) in my activity instead of writing the whole description in my strings.XML file. If yes please help me with the code. Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8695590/3110234

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read .txt and display it as TextView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695361/how-can-i-read-txt-and-display-it-as-textview-in-android)

Comment: @activesince93 I want to add .txt in my project like in assets or raw folder not from SD card

Comment: @UmaKanth I want to add .txt in my project like in assets or raw folder not from SD card

Comment: try replacing "getContext().getAssets()" with "sdcard"

Answer (score 0):

[There are a few decent answers to this in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android)

```
//Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
//*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}

//Find the view by its id
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);

//Set the text
tv.setText(text.toString());
```

Unless this is something that is dependant upon reading from a possibly changing .txt file, you should definitely try to use the strings XML file.